# Ignore Dockerfile in gitlab-ci Pipeline

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to bypass the automatic Dockerfile procedure during a gitlab Pipeline?
I haven't configured the docker registry and my Git Repository is not able to process the Docker features using CI/CD.
Is there an easy way to just ignore the Dockerfile in my Project or modify gitlab-ci.yml to exclude Docker runs?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run your jobs in docker then register [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) and configure your jobs to run on it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Is there a quick and dirty way to skip the whole Docker stage in the pipeline? I haven't found an entry in the gitlab-ci configuration documentation that allows e.g. to skip Dockerfile evaluation automatically.

Comment: Is this your private gitlab instance or are you using public gitlab.com? If this is your private instance then you can ask your admin to register shell runner. I'd go to `Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners` there you can see available runners and instruction how to register your own runner.